# Limit Cisco IP phone to only one subnet ranges DHCP

Tags: cisco, subnet, voip

We run stretched layer 2 and we have the e911 service setup to correspond for each location.  We run different sub-nets for each location as well.  I'm wondering if there is a way to limit a users phone to only accept a DHCP Lease from a specific sub-net.  The phones do run on their own VLAN, but this doesn't solve our e911 issue.

Alternately, is there a way to receive a notification or auto assign the information based on the information.

Again, ideally I'd like to simply not allow the phone to connect if it changes sub-nets which would force the user to call the tech desk to have the phone provisioned again.

If it's relevant...The city our HQ is located in actually has three buildings in completely different parts of town.  On occasion we will have an employee decide to move (or get moved by management) but they don't notify IT which causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information provided, the easiest solution is to associate the VLAN ID with a DHCP scope on the DHCP server.

For a more concise answer, or insight into what other options you may have available, it would help to know the quantity and type of appliances or servers used for DHCP, if the phones are PoE, CDP-enabled and what type of device is being used at the first hop from the phones (e.g., Phone -> Jack -> Patch -> Catalyst #### series).

Comment: *3560 & 3560-X switches *PoE Enabled  *CDP Enabled  *As to the assigned VLAN.  We already have a company wide VLAN and corresponding DHCP Pool.  So just to make sure I understand this suggestion...Assign each location it's own VLAN and DHCP scope for VOIP?